Why my wiki pages cannot be linked to canvas app?
I'm creating an helpdesk app for users in my company. My access to sharepoint is kinda limited, but I can create/edit sites on my team sharepoint site + have access to Power Apps.
I wanted to create an app that will be a vertical gallery displaying sites from Page Library as articles that user can scroll.
Can you please give me some tips or ideas how can I connect Page library localisation to canvas app?
I'm not using WikiPages app from classic Sharepoint. I made a template that after creating an article is stored in Site Pages (page library) in main Site Contents repository.
I've tried to modify Higlighted content webpart, but I cannot integrate it with modern wiki pages.
Used Modern Script editor but seems like lack of skill to make it work.
